# Identification electronic component

Tags: identification

[image]

Hi,

What is the Part number of this component?

Top mark : S0 N

Analog Devices

Do you have any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ask the manufacturer?

Answer (score 1):

I believe its a ADG804, 4:1 multiplexer

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG804.pdf